# Highchart js bar graph label left alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to align all of the labels in this Highchart.js bar graph to the left so that they don't overlap the bar. However, Highchart.js seems to override the css that I add.

Does anyone know how to move these labels to the left of the bars and still have them aligned to the left?

```
 xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Injustice: Gods Among Us ★', 'Tekken Tag Tournament 2 ★', 'Super Smash Bros. Melee ★', 'Persona 4 Arena', 'King of Fighters XIII', 'Dead or Alive 5 Ultimate', 'Street Fighter X Tekken Ver. 2013', 'Soulcalibur V'],
        labels: {
            align: 'left', 
            overflow: 'justify',
            style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    fontSize: '20px',
                    color: '#333',
                    width: '350', 
                    left: '-20px', 
                    x: 0
               },
            formatter: function () {
                return '<div> <span>' + this.value + '</span><span style="font-weight: bold">' + " " + '</span> </div>';
            },
            useHTML: true
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/butlerjeff1/prcoo7vy/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523582/highcharts-how-to-push-the-categories-to-the-side/31538731#31538731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `align: 'left'` in the labels object actually does the opposite to what you want. Try taking it out and the labels will pop back to the left of the axis.

Then, to tidy it up, add a text-align:right to your label formatter:

```
formatter: function () {
    return '<div style="text-align:right"> <span>' + this.value + '</span><span style="font-weight: bold">' + " " + '</span> </div>';
},
```

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prcoo7vy/3/)

**EDIT**
Sorry, I misread your post. You can keep `align:left` but then add `x:-300` to the labels object which will nudge them back to the left side of the axis (I've chosen 300 to match the left margin you set but of course you can edit it to whatever you want)

[New Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/prcoo7vy/4/)

Comment: Hey Ella, thanks for responding. When you remove the align: left the labels do move to the left of the bar however they are no longer aligned left. Instead they appear to be aligned right.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'reserveSpace: true' in your xAxis label and remove formatter, style(width, x, left), useHTML.

This will help you to get your required output

http://jsfiddle.net/prcoo7vy/24/

```
xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Injustice: Gods Among Us ★', 'Tekken Tag Tournament 2 ★', 'Super Smash Bros. Melee ★', 'Persona 4 Arena', 'King of Fighters XIII', 'Dead or Alive 5 Ultimate', 'Street Fighter X Tekken Ver. 2013', 'Soulcalibur V'],
        labels: {
            align: 'left', 
            overflow: 'justify',
            reserveSpace: true,
            style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    fontSize: '20px',
                    color: '#333'
               },

      }]
```